# Can't fabricate many items with Fabrication-gem and Mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, mongoid, database-cleaner, fabrication-gem

I'm using Fabrication-gem gem, with DatabaseCleaner and Mongoid ORM on RSpec tests. Here are my scripts:

**spec/support/database_cleaner.rb**

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
  end
end
```

**spec/fabricators/client_fabricators.rb**

```
Fabricator(:client) do
  auth_id { (SecureRandom.hex)[0..3] }
  base_url { Faker::Internet.url }
end
```

Finally, **spec/requests/clients_spec.rb**

```
before(:all) do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
  @clients = Fabricate.times(2, :client)
end

after(:all) do # Use after :all so data stays around until the end of the block
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end

it {...}
it {...}
...
```

Unfortunately, I get as many errors as I have `it {...}` blocks in my `context`, all with the same error message from Mongoid:

```
Failure/Error: @clients = Fabricate.times(2, :client)
Mongoid::Errors::DocumentNotFound:

  Problem:
    Document not found for class Client with attributes {:auth_id=>"7123"}.
```

Note that if I use `@clients = Fabricate.times(1, :client)` (which means fabricate only one client) it works perfectly. So I think that the problem is in DatabaseCleaner (I tried many configurations, but all unsuccessfully).

I'm using Ruby 2.2.0, Rails 4.2.0 (rails-api, to be exact), DatabaseCleaner 1.4.1, Mongoid 4.0.2 and Fabrication 2.13.1

Do you have any idea on how to fix that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it might be an issue with your test setup and when database_cleaner is being executed. Typically one would set it up to encapsulate each example run individually, not as before and after :all.

However, if you are only using it to clean out your mongoid documents I think you could just ditch it entirely. Fabrication runs this before each example in its own test suite. You may want to give that a try instead.

`Mongoid::Config.purge!`

https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/blob/master/spec/support/mongoid.rb#L5